# Stack overflow: DynamicClass with Mapster and Regular Expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex, stack-overflow, mapster

I am not sure what exactly can be calling this but is there anything odd with my cleanText function that is run within a property.  Every once in a while we get this stack overflow issue but not sure what text was sent.

```
Stack overflow: DynamicClass.(ArrayClosure, System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1) [Stack Overflow]
First seen: 2/7/2024, 7:00:00 PM
Last seen: 2/7/2024, 7:21:47 PM
Crashes: 8
I am getting this Stack Overflow exception below very rarely but not sure how it is happening.

Stack Overflow

Recommendation
A developer should review the code in DynamicClass.(ArrayClosure, System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1) to determine why it recursively invokes itself, and make sure that recursion is terminated correctly when a stop condition is reached, or that the depth is limited. If large depths are expected, "unroll" the code to a while loop instead.
```

**Member.cs**

```
public string MobilePhone
{
    get { return _mobilePhone; }
    set { _mobilePhone = Helper.CleanPhoneNumber(value); }
}
```

CleanText

```
public static string CleanPhoneNumber(string phoneNumber)
 {
     return CleanText(phoneNumber);
 }

    public static string CleanText(string text)
    {
        if (text == null)
            return null;

        return Regex.Replace(text, "[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "").Replace(" ", "").ToLower();
    }
```

**Mapping Code**

```
 config.NewConfig<Member, MemberModel>()
     .Map(d => d.Api, s => s.Api).PreserveReference(true);
```

Stack Trace

```
1. System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.ctor(...)
2. System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(...)
3. Tournaments.Common.Utility.Helper.CleanText(...)
4. Tournaments.Common.Utility.Helper.CleanPhoneNumber(...)
5. Tournaments.Data.Entities.Member.set_MobilePhone(...)
6. DynamicClass.(
7. DynamicClass.(

.
.
.
164. DynamicClass.(...)
165. DynamicClass.(
166. MapsterMapper.ServiceMapper.Map[[System.__Canon, mscorlib],[System.__Canon, mscorlib]](...)
167. Tournaments.Services.Organizations.OrganizationsService.GetForMember(...)
```

Comment: How about posting the mapping code too?

Comment: I added it but it doesnt show much

Comment: The stack overflow doesn't appear to be related to the regex, otherwise it wouldn't 'end'.  Where does the report about the SO come from?

Comment: LeanSentry which is a monitoring service

Comment: Not an answer, but `Regex.Replace(text, "[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "")` can be improved by changing it to `Regex.Replace(text, "[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", "")`. This replaces sequences of one or more characters rather than changing characters one at a time. Additionally a space is one of the non-alphanumerics found by the regex, hence the `Replace(" ", "")` is redundant.

Comment: How long are the strings being processed? I wonder whether the overhead of managing many replacements within a very large string is causing the overflow. Having written that, I would expect phone numbers to be quite small. Might it be called with something that is not a phone number?

Comment: Only 9 characters in length, all numbers as a string.  I have test cases setup to verify strings but everything works fine.  Ill try the Regex for now but I know that probably isn't the fix.  The length going in I guess depends if a user puts 1-555-555-5555, etc, however this is a DB call that has all values set to 9 in length

Comment: I would be inclined to add code of the form `if (text.length > 10) { throw(something); }` after the `return null;` just to rule out long strings. (Maybe 100 or 1000 rather than 10.)

Comment: @AdrianHHH ITU E.164 Standard says 15 is the absolute maximum phone number length, without any formatting

Comment: I am just doing US